# Remove items from chart _yField in EXTJS 5

Tags: charts, extjs, extjs5

Hello all Here i have chart data like below

Data looks like on legndheading = ['g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6','g7','g8']

I want to remove last two items from legndheading and update to series[0]._yField

```
var legndheading = series[0]._yField;

legndheading = ['g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6','g7','g8']
```

remove last two items and append to series[0]._yField

i tried to remove but not working

```
series[0]._yField.RemoveAt(5);
```

But it's not working

Comment: Please create a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate your issue. Without the code it is really hard to help.